# Resource not found Exception using a Library

Tags: android

I have a project B I am using as a library and referencing from project A.

My understanding is two separate R files will be generated for the Project A and Project B(Library), in the GEN directory of Project A.

During runtime I am getting the following error:
07-27 20:55:42.520: D/PrtotbufAstron..:(20732): String resource ID #0x7f0a00ab
07-27 20:55:42.520: W/ResourceType(20732): getEntry failing because entryIndex 157 is beyond type entryCount 1
07-27 20:55:42.520: W/ResourceType(20732): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0a009d (t=9 e=157) in package 0 (error -2147483647)

The resource ID is actually in the R file of the Project B (Library):

```
public static int geminids=0x7f0a017f;
```

The same resource in the Project A auto-generated R file is:

```
public static final int geminids = 0x7f090199;
```

So I am not sure why the ID allocated to the same resource is different in the R file of the 
library and the R file in Project A.

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting that error in Runtime or when you try to start your app?

Comment: Getting it in runtime. My understanding is a separate R file for the libary will be generated in Project A alongside Project A R file, can't see why the ids are diff

Comment: Is that only happening when you enter some screen or do a specific task in your app? Try to clean both projects and build them again.

Comment: Thanks but have cleaned and built both project A and Libary with same result...

Comment: From reading the documentation I am unclear as to wether a R file should be generated during a build for the libary itself....but a R file should def be generated for the reference project (project A)...any ideas?

Comment: @dancingbush - Did you ever find a solution? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @jheimbouch sorry no can't help never did find a solution and out of touch with android dev now, I suspected the project b I was using as a library for Project A Was somehow not compiled as such, in fact when I uploaded the project to google play two APKs were generated, one for each project

Comment: I converted the project B from a project to a library in Eclipse- then added to project A, somehow I think  the conversion to library is where the problem was